# Using itoa() results in: "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast"

Tags: c, string, type-conversion, integer, prototype

I am working on BCD (Binary Coded Decimal) in C and in charge of writing the different bcd functions.

I need to encode an integer i into buffer char *s of size n. The function returns 0 on success or -1 in case of an overflow (encoding i requires a buffer larger than n).

Here is the function: `int bcd_encode(int i, int n, char *s)`

and a sample input: `assert(bcd_encode(a, 128, s) == 0);`

I am writing the code for the function bcd_encode and correct me if I am wrong but I believe in a function and only in a function if you were to have some `func(char x[])` and char `func(char *x)` they would be the same thing? So you can look at both of them as a char array. If it were outside the function definition `char x[];` would be an char array and `char *x;` would be a pointer.

```
int bcd_encode(int i, int n, char *s){  
    int j = 0;  
    s = itoa(i, s, n+1);  
}
```

But this returns a warning "assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast" and a undefined symbol for itoa. I've tried a few different variations from

*s = itoa(i);
s = itoa(i);
s = itoa(i, s, n+1);

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you wanna return an `int` at the end of the function?

Comment: `itoa` is MSVC++ only (AFAIK). It's not standard C.

Comment: It's not standard C, but it's widely implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> ...  and correct me if I am wrong but I believe in a function and only in a function if you were to have some func(char x[]) and char func(char *x) they would be the same thing? So you can look at both of them as a char array. If it were outside the function definition char x[]; would be an char array and char *x; would be a pointer.

It would be better to regard them both as pointers (rather than both as arrays) inside the function, but you've got the key point - in function argument lists, the distinctions between arrays and pointers are blurred, but elsewhere pointers and arrays are different.

In the code, since `itoa()` is assumed to return an integer in the absence of information to the contrary, you cannot store that in a pointer or as a pointer (without using a sledgehammer cast, which would leave your code broken).

What does `itoa()` return?  It isn't a standard C function (as in, not in ISO/IEC 9899:1999, nor in POSIX).  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itoa) suggests it returns no value, so you should not be assigning its value anywhere. [Linux](http://linux.die.net/man/3/itoa) has it as a non-standard extension in `<stdlib.h>` with a different interface that returns a `char *` (which is the value of its second argument).  You can safely ignore the return value; in fact, you can also do the assignment (after including the header) but the assignment is a no-op.  You do need to know that the function is non-standard, that it has a variety of definitions, and therefore you have to be aware of what is correct for your platform, or avoid using it (maybe by using `snprintf()` instead).

---

Quoting the linked Linux manual page:

> ```
> char* itoa (int __val, char * __s, int __radix)
> ```
>
> Convert an integer to a string.
>
> The function itoa() converts the integer value from val into an ASCII representation that will be stored under s. The caller is responsible for providing sufficient storage in s.
>
> **Note:**
>    The minimal size of the buffer s depends on the choice of radix. For example, if the radix is 2 (binary), you need to supply a buffer with a minimal length of 8 * sizeof (int) + 1 characters, i.e. one character for each bit plus one for the string terminator. Using a larger radix will require a smaller minimal buffer size. 
>   **Warning:**
>    If the buffer is too small, you risk a buffer overflow. 
>   Conversion is done using the radix as base, which may be a number between 2 (binary conversion) and up to 36. If radix is greater than 10, the next digit after '9' will be the letter 'a'.
>
> If radix is 10 and val is negative, a minus sign will be prepended.
>
> The itoa() function returns the pointer passed as s.

You don't want to use `n+1` as the radix.

Comment: Ahh thx for correcting me on that first part. I believed `itoa()` to return the char value.

Comment: Rather than believing things, look them up. You will be much happier for it, as will your employers, cow orkers, and clients.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Without that include, the compiler doesn't know anything about `itoa()` and will assume it returns an `int`.

Comment: hmm I had stdio.h not the stdlib however it still does the error (So I will keep digging)

Comment: It's not standard C, so the #include location may vary.  See the docs for your system/compiler.

Answer (score 1):

> The function returns 0 on success or
>   -1 in case of an overflow (encoding i requires a buffer larger than n).

And yet you aren't doing that.

> int j = 0;

What's that for?

> s = itoa(i, s, n+1);

Why are you assigning to s?

> I've tried a few different variations
>   from
>
> *s = itoa(i); s = itoa(i); s = itoa(i, s, n+1);

Trying things randomly until you stumble upon one that works is not a good approach to programming.

Assigning to either s or *s is inappropriate here and shows a poor understanding of C; I strongly advise obtaining more instruction in the language. Once you have done that, you can use snprintf, e.g.,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int bcd_encode(int i, int n, char *s){  
    int r = snprintf(s, n, "%d", i);
    return r < n? 0 : -1;  
}
```

assuming that s is supposed to be NUL-terminated and that n includes the NUL -- those details aren't specified in your description.

BTW, that's not what "BCD" means -- see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal

Answer (score 0):

itoa() is undefined means you are missing the header file

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
```

If it's not defined the complier assumes the unknown function itoa() returns an int (for stupid historical reasons).

Always listen to compiler warnings - they are your friend !

Comment: I've been learning to listen to compiler errors more. Even though I added <stdlib.h> it still gives me same error... I'm thinking it is something with my char *s

Comment: it means you don't have an itoa() - check your compiler docs you probably have something with a similar name eg. _itoa()